# Pronunciations of "class" as found in Collins American English Dictionary

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, dictionaries, dialect

The [Collins American English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/class?showCookiePolicy=true) gives

**class** two pronunciations, presumably with respect to American English.

Does this mean American English speakers use both equally and that both are okay?
(Btw, English is a second language for me.)

Comment: @pazzo I disagree;  it seems to me that even if the practice here is peculiar to Collins, the larger question of How to use a dictionary is pretty central to language learning -- particularly since we accept Collins as an 'authority' and indeed require questioners to consult such an authority before they present their questions here.

Comment: To OP, for what it's worth, my opinion is that it's not equally likely in the sense that a person will sometimes use one pronunciation and sometimes the alternate one. Most people will pronounce a word (virtually) consistently, and that's part of what we think of as dialect. This topic is quite complex. (For one thing, I can't speak every dialect of my first language perfectly. I think not many people can, in any language.) For starters, check out the vowel chart on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects.

Comment: Well I would retract my close vote, and the rationale behind it, would the question not be reedited to read *Dictionary conventions when indicating alternate pronunciations*, an edit of @TRomano that throws a good specific question to the wind of vagaries.

Comment: @pazzo: I was editing the title to reflect what I saw to be the general question posed in the body of the post, taking "class" to be merely an example.

Comment: The original question, title and body, asks only about "class," as far as I read it. @TR

Comment: @pazzo: Not unreasonable on your part. It depends on how one understands  "does this mean" and "equally".

Comment: "Do American speakers use both pronunciations equally?" would suggest that the question is specifically about the word "class". "Does this mean…" suggests that the OP is interested the general question, and "class" is only an example. Either way, an answer should address the general question as well as the example, because we _explain_ things on ELL. Closevoting a question over a fine point of wording, which a learner, being a learner, might not understand, when it doesn't affect the answer, is not helpful.

Answer (score 11):

You should be aware that Collins is not an entirely reliable authority for American pronunciation.<sup>†</sup>

I can't find any statement on the Collins site detailing their approach to phonetic representation, and there's a lot of wiggle room in 'broad' transcriptions representing phonology; but I think this particular representation is flat wrong.

In my experience, US pronunciation of *class* ranges from /klas/ through 'Standard' /klæs/ to a diphthongalized /klæᵻs/ (and even /klæjɪs/!); but /klɑs/ would occur only with speakers deliberately emulating British speech.

There are a *lot* of different realizations in AmE for the /æs/ collocation, which in practice will all be perceived as identical by any US speaker; but /klɑs/ will be perceived as 'foreign'.

---

<sup>†</sup> [Here](http://www.antimoon.com/how/cobuild-review.htm)'s a review which corroborates this judgment.

Comment: Could they be referring to certain Boston accent speakers? Wikipedia mentions the "broad a" being used by some in that region (on the pages [Northeastern New England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_England_English#Northeastern_New_England), [Phonological history of English short A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_short_A#Trap.E2.80.93bath_split), and [Boston accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_accent#Vowels), though with some "citations needed".)

Comment: @DanGetz The Boston 'broad a' is [a] where RP has [ɑ].

Comment: @StoneyB You mentioned Collin is not reliable authority for American pronunciation, may I know are there reliable sources I can refer to? As I am not a native speaker, I can't distinguish them.